# Creation of the heap region/segment in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, memory-management

It's my understanding that on Linux the process loader doesn't automatically create a "heap" region for a process like it's the case for the stack, is that correct?

I used `/proc/$$/maps` and before the call to `malloc()` there was no "heap" region.

Answer (score 5):

Linux does not "automatically create" a region for both, heap and stack segments.

In programming languages there is always an entry point, where control is transferred from the operating system to the program. In C, this is the `main()` function.

Each process in Linux has a memory mapping of 4GB in 32-Bit and 8TB in 64-Bit environments. This is the maximum amout of memory that is possible to address by the operating system. Notice, that this is independent of how many physical memory your system really has. Every process is giving the illusion that it is alone on the computer.

Before calling `main()`, the operating system pushes the elements of the command line, that was used to invoke the program, on "top" of the initially empty stack, this is where the *stack segment* is. If the `main()` calls itself a function the passing arguments are pushed in the stack segment.

```
 4GB/8TB┌───────────┐
        │   stack   │ <- main(), argc/argv parameters and functions, growing downwards
        ├ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┤
        │           │
        │           │ <- empty
        │           │
        │           │
        ├───────────┤
        │   data    │ <- static data and literal constants
        ├───────────┤
        │   text    │ <- all the instructions; the compiled code
       0└───────────┘
```

---

Now your question:

> I used `/proc/$$/maps` and before the call to malloc there was no "heap" region.

The **heap memory**: A process can expand into the unoccupied portion of virtual memory at runtime using the `malloc()` system call. This **dynamically allocated memory** is located above *data* in the *heap segment*. So it is normal, that there is no heap region or segment until the first `malloc()` call.

```
 4GB/8TB┌───────────┐
        │   stack   │ <- main(), argc/argv parameters and functions, growing downwards
        ├ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┤
        │           │
        │           │ <- empty
        ├ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┤
        │   heap    │ <- malloc()'d memory space, growing upwards
        ├───────────┤
        │   data    │ <- static data and literal constants
        ├───────────┤
        │   text    │ <- all the instructions; the compiled code
       0└───────────┘
```

Comment: is the memory mapped region part of the heap?